How to use the stft function?
I have SAR measurement data in the form no.of range gate x no.of pulses for 4 channels. I want to apply stft function from matlab to get the Time-Frequency spectrogram. But the function from matlab takes only 1 dimensional signal as an input. So, I can give one range gate at a time and get S which is of dimension $100 \times 45$ (freq vs time).
To apply stft for all range gates, do I loop through all the range gates one by one and compute S and stack it row-wise like [S1;S2;....;Sn] where n is the no.of range gates?
[S, f, t] = stft(20*log10(data(1,:)), 'Window', hamming(window), 'OverlapLength', noverlap, 'FFTLength', nfft, 'Centered', false);
S_abs = abs(fftshift((S)));


My ultimate goal is to observe the time-frequency spectrum and feed them to a neural network which will identify jamming from the spectrum.

There needs to be quite a bit of clarification here. Can you edit your question to clarify, for example what format is your SAR data in (raw collected, demodulated, dechirped, etc.), and whether or not you want slow time or fast time to be transformed into the frequency domain?

I have added an image of how the time-freq spectrogram across a single range gate looks like.

Since you can equate pulse number with time, if you take just the FFT in the range dimension, you will have frequency vs. (slow-)time for each channel. If you want to look at frequency vs. fast-time, then you have to do the STFT on an individual pulse.
You could turn the data for each channel into a 1-D array by inserting the proper number of zeros between the pulses and vec()'ing the data, but that seems wasteful, since you'll be storing and processing a bunch of zeros (typically). Moreover, taking the STFT of each individual pulse and creating a 4-D array (frequency x fast-time x slow-time x channel) will provide the same amount of information more efficiently.

stftResult = zeros(nFreqBins, nTimeSegments, nPulses, nChannels);
for pulseIdx = 1:nPulses
pulseData = dataMatrix(:, pulseIdx);
[S, F, T] = spectrogram(pulseData, windowLength, overlap, nFFT, 'yaxis');

stftResult(:, :, pulseIdx, 1) = abs(S(1:nFreqBins, :));  

end.....   Are you suggesting something like this ?

Yes. Something along these lines. The specifics are up to you of course.
